# Test environment for an Online Judge

Tags: c++, c, testing

I am planning to build an Online Judge on the lines of CodeChef, TechGig, etc. Initially, I will be accepting solutions only in C/C++.

Have thought through a security model for the same, but my concern as of now is how to model the execution and testing part.

**Method 1**

The method that seems to be more popular is to redirect standard input to the executable and redirect standard output to a file, for example:

```
./submission.exe < input.txt > output.txt
```

Then compare the output.txt file with some solution.txt file character by character and report the results.

**Method 2**

A second approach that I have seen is not to allow the users to write main(). Instead, write a function that accepts some arguments in the form of strings and set a global variable as the output. For example:

```
//This variable should be set before returning from submissionAlgorithm()
char * output; 

void submissionAlgorithm(char * input1, char * input2)
{
    //Write your code here.
}
```

At each step, and for a test case to be executed, the function submissionAlgorithm() is repeatedly called and the output variable is checked for results.

Form an initial analysis I found that Method 2 would not only be secure (I would prevent all read and write access to the filesystem from the submitted code), but also make the execution of test cases faster (maybe?) since the computations of test results would occur in memory.

I would like to know if there is any reason as to why Method 1 would be preferred over Method 2.

P.S: Of course, I would be hosting the online judge engine on a Linux Server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't take this wrong, but you will need to look at security from a much higher perspective. The problem will not be the input and output being written to a file, and that should not affect performance too much either. But you will need to manage submisions that can actually take down your process (in the second case) or the whole system (with calls to the OS to write to disk, acquire too much memory....)

**Disclaimer** I am by no means a security expert.

Comment: @AakashRoy: Start by setting up a chroot environment with a user that has no permissions to access basically anything at all to run the tests. You should even consider *compiling* in a chroot environment with limited libraries, and analyzing the code/binary to ensure that no system calls are generated from the solutions... Then consider that commits will be incorrect, and they might acquire too much memory (consider limiting with `ulimit`), or run into an infinite loop (have a process watching the submission and kill the process if it takes too much time/cpu)...

Comment: I have read quite a bit on the security aspects. For more clarity, I am listing down in brief what I have already implemented so far from the security perspective:  1. The executable would run in a Sandboxed environment with limited user permissions to only read and write within a particular designated folder. 2. Tracing disallowed system calls using ptrace. 3. Setting memory and time quotas for each such process using setrlimit() system call. 4. Putting a disk quota usage policy on the server. Contd in next comment...

Comment: 4.In the designated sandbox (chroot jail), only designated header files and libraries will be available. Having said this, I would like to know is there still a way Method 2 will be better/ worse in terms of security and performance.

Comment: @AakashRoy: Security will be slightly better with method 1. In the first approach the OS will force separation of the process, in the second method, a misbehaving process might affect your way of analyzing the program, a crash in user code will tear your program down, etc. If you are concerned on IO (I wouldn't) consider creating a small memory disk (couple of megs, whatever your output size should be and some extra space)

Comment: When you say "Method 2", do you mean it in addition to all the things from "Method 1"? Because I don't see how "Method 2" alone has any kind of security measure. One could submit code to walk up the stack and mess up with the code calling `submissionAlgorithm` for example. Chrooted environments are popular with automated judges for a reason.

Comment: @David: In Method 2, there will be a file already present in the system with main() implemented. When the user submits the code, the user's algo is written to the file. The file is compiled, and if compilation is successful, it will always be run on a separate process. Hence "a misbehaving process might affect your way of analyzing the program, a crash in user code will tear your program down" is actually not a concern.

Comment: @Daniel: It is not a concern, since to walk up the stack, the user has to use some sort of system call, eg. walkcontext(). I am not allowing such system calls in the first place. Secondly, the compiled C code will be running in a separate process. Please see my previous comment for more info on the same.

Comment: `malloc()` is also a system call; do you expect only code with no system calls? Are you checking for all possible assembly payloads too? I can walk up the stack by hand too. What I mean is, "Method 2" is impracticable, there are just too many holes to plug.

Comment: @AakashRoy: You don't need to use any system call to walk up your stack, the whole stack is in memory mapped to the process the simple way of walking up the stack is by knowing a bit about the architecture (or assume intel 32/64 which can be determined by the size of a pointer), and then knowing the calling convention

Comment: @ Daniel: I am maintaining a whitelist of system calls that I will allow. Malloc is in the whitelist along with few other functions. Others will be blocked. Ex: fork(). I have got your points. Yes, walking the stack can be a threat. As pointed out by David,  I may not be able to analyze what caused the process to crash / get killed.